keycloak integration with oracle on openshift cloud

I am trying to install keycloak 24.02 on Openshift 4.14 with oracle 19.3, I was able to build custom keyclock 24.02 image with this.I am able to get the login UI but getting below error in the pod logs after the login page in admin console
2024-06-12 10:01:10,186 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-32) type="LOGIN_ERROR", realmId="2280ecdf-46b0-4b7a-825c-7fad173b74c5", clientId="null", userId="null", ipAddress="10.255.28.2", error="cookie_not_found"
I tried to login with admin user . i need to login without error .i will paste Dockerfile used to create custome image .
Docekrfile
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2
ADD --chown=keycloak:keycloak --chmod=644 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc11/23.3.0.23.09/ojdbc11-23.3.0.23.09.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/ojdbc11.jar
ADD --chown=keycloak:keycloak --chmod=644 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/nls/orai18n/23.3.0.23.09/orai18n-23.3.0.23.09.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/orai18n.jar
# Setting the build parameter for the database:
ENV KC_DB=oracle
# Add all other build parameters needed, for example enable health and metrics:
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx.tre.xxx-rdnet.net:1521:cdb1
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=Usxxxxx
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=Paszxxx
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminpass
# To be able to use the image with the Red Hat build of Keycloak Operator, it needs to be optimized, which requires Red Hat build of Keycloak's build step:
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev"]


# keycloak-statefulset.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: keycloak-chatgpt
  namespace: keycloak-new-ns
spec:
  serviceName: "keycloak"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: harbor-core-doc-common-svc.apps.xxxx.tre.xxx-rdnet.net/library/keycloak:24.0.2_test15
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: DB_VENDOR
              value: oracle
            - name: DB_ADDR
              value: xxxxnode01.tre.xxx-rdnet.net
            - name: DB_PORT
              value: "1521"
            - name: DB_DATABASE
              value: cdb1
            - name: DB_USER
              value: User090
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              value: Pass090
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
              value: admin
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              value: adminpass
            - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-secret
                  key: admin-password
          volumeMounts:
            - name: keycloak-data
              mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: keycloak-data
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi

keycloak-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: keycloak-new-ns
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: keycloak

route.yaml
kind: Route
metadata:
  annotations:
    route.openshift.io/termination: edge
    openshift.io/host.generated: "true"
    router.openshift.io/cookie_name: keycloak
  creationTimestamp: "2024-06-11T16:59:42Z"
  name: keycloak
  namespace: keycloak-new-ns
  resourceVersion: "178305302"
  uid: e205fa8c-f4d9-4ed8-9865-eac9ab4af936
spec:
  host: keyclock-keyclock-new-ns.apps.xxxx.tre.xxx-rdnet.net
  port:
    targetPort: 8080
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: keycloak
    weight: 100
  wildcardPolicy: None
status:
  ingress:
  - conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: "2024-06-11T16:59:42Z"
      status: "True"
      type: Admitted
    host: keyclock-keyclock-new-ns.apps.xxxx.tre.xxx-rdnet.net
    routerCanonicalHostname: router-default.apps.xxxx.tre.xxx-rdnet.net
    routerName: default
    wildcardPolicy: None



